# SATA Expansion Card

Tags: sata

I've been struggling to install an nVidia RTX 3050 card in my machine and keep running into hiccups. The latest hiccup, now that I've got everything else settled, is that the card doesn't quite fit. It would, except that it wants to be on top of the 4 SATA connectors that my drives are connected to.

So a SATA expansion card is no problem, but **here's my question**:

If I move my system drive to a SATA expansion card, will my system still boot from it? If not, this is all for naught and I don't want to buy yet another thing (after the power supply and then the 8 pin to 4 pin 12V connector), only to find out it's not going to work for me.

Comment: Do you already have 90° SATA connectors & it still doesn't fit?

Comment: If I use a 90 degree connector, it will cover over 3 of the 4 connectors and I need all 4. The video card won't seat entirely with a 90 degree connector either. It might be good enough, but it's an expensive card, I'd rather not risk it being unaligned.

Comment: Regarding "If I use a 90 degree connector, it will cover over 3 of the 4 connectors and I need all 4"  No, you need 1 SATA drive to guarantee your system will boot the other 3+ SATA device can plug into any expansion card.  Does that help?  The problem with expansion cards is you need to do manual research on each one to see if it bootable.